# How to use raster calculator on WMS layers?

Tags: wms, raster-calculator, lidar

I'm using lidar data (UK Environment Agency) from a WMS server and would like to use this in the raster calculator. When I go to the raster calculator the WMS layers aren't an option.

The data is also available for download in ASC format, which can be made into virtual raster format that seems to work with the raster calculator. However, the lidar dataset can only be downloaded this way in small sections and it would be very time consuming to do this.

Is there a way to either:

1 - get the WMS layer to work in the raster calculator?

2 - download all the data from the WMS server and save it in a format that works with the raster calculator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WMS provides you a picture of the data so there is no way to use it for calculations.

You can download the Lidar data directly using a shell script and curl or wget as the url is very regular.

Comment: Ah i see, that makes sense, thanks for explaining. Shell scripts might be a bit above my ability, but apparently Airbus (who run the download tool for the EA) can provide the complete set for a nominal fee (£200+vat).

Comment: can you share the data after that?

Comment: not sure, think it should be okay with the license but not 100%. The issue would be that just the composite data is over 600GB, so practically quite hard to share. I guess hence why Airbus have to manually put it on a hard drive you send in.

Comment: figures, of course they could just stick it up on a decent WCS server and let us download what we need